# How to use poetry publish to store whl to s3?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I used `poetry build` to create `my_package.whl` now I want to use `poetry publish` to publish it. I want to publish it to **my own s3 bucket** and **not to PYPI**. I tried to find an example online but couldn't find one. can someone share a link or example?

Comment: the publish command expects a [PEP503](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/) conform web-server, which an s3 bucket isn't. That means that you can't configure `poetry publish` just like that, and probably have to find some kind of `awscli` command to do what you want.

Comment: this project sounds like it tries to solve the same or a similar issue that you have https://www.novemberfive.co/blog/opensource-pypi-package-repository-tutorial

Comment: These is a still open issue about supporting s3pypi publishing in poetry issues - https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3173.